# Bootstrap DatePicker Position

Tags: html, css, datepicker

How can I change position of where the calendar pops up. I am using the below code and the calendar pops up to the far left.

[image: Current result]

I need it to pop up over the input field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../datepicker/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type='text/javascript'> 
    </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link href='../datepicker/bootstrap/css' rel='stylesheet' 
    type='text/css'>
    <script src=../datepicker/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js 
    type='text/javascript'></script>
    <!-- Datepicker -->
    <link href='../datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap- 
    datepicker.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src='../datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap- 
    datepicker.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div align="center">
    <h4>Date Range for Chart</h4>
<form method="post" action="mychart2.php">
<p>Start Date: <input type="text" name = "start" data-provide="datepicker" 
data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd"></p>
<p>End Date:   <input type="text" name = "end"   data-provide="datepicker" 
data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd"></p>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I not sure I can control the position by using data-provide

Comment: Try target the css directly on the element to position it to your liking. Look into `magin` and perhaps `Z-index`.

Comment: how is your `date-picker popup` shown share screen shot

Comment: Why is there a -1???? What does that mean?

Comment: @gary_1946 It means that you received a downvote. There are multiple reasons why you may receive it. Like: the question does not follow "How to ask a question" (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80538/how-to-ask-questions-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: Well not sure I agree. I am 72 years old and have been programming for over 30 years. Now ture I don't do it for a living, but I do have some knowledge of what I am doing. I think a forum is a great place to get help, not a place to criticize someone looking for help.  I consider constructive criticism an  oxymoron. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that you use the Bootstrap CSS. It seems that the Bootstrap is not loaded properly.

You can set the HTML property `data-date-orientation` according to the [documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#orientation):

> A space-separated string consisting of one or two of “left” or “right”, “top” or “bottom”, and “auto” (may be omitted); for example, “top left”, “bottom” (horizontal orientation will default to “auto”), “right” (vertical orientation will default to “auto”), “auto top”. Allows for fixed placement of the picker popup.

Each option attribute has to have the `data-date-` prefix.

The distance to the input field may be controller by setting the margin.

Comment: I saw that in documentation when I was researching a solution,  but could not get it to work. I used data-date-orientation="top right" and it still popped up lower left

Comment: @gary_1946 Could you provide a picture by editing your question?

Comment: Here is a screen shot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q5dub2p1pblrwjl/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: It seems that you don't use the Bootstrap styling. Are you getting any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: I am useing Chrome development tools and no errors. I am using bootstrap css. I have not messed with the css yet because I wanted to see if there was a way to position it.

Comment: Positioning is done by CSS. The CSS class(es) that are used, come from the Bootstrap CSS file.

Comment: That is all I needed to know. I am can handle the css.

Comment: So this is the solution to your problem? If so, please mark reply as answer :-)