# How to change position of Bootstrap datepicker pop-up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using bootstrap datepicker (https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html) and everything works fine except the datepicker pop-up appears on top instead of the bottom. I have checked multiple answers and none have helped.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
  <input id="dateAssigned" name="dateAssigned" type="text" class="form-control mb-4 mt-1" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
  <div class="input-group-addon"></div>
</div>
```

And here is JS. I tried with WidgetPositioning:

```
    <script>
        $('#dateAssigned').datepicker({
            widgetPositioning: {
                horizontal: 'left',
                vertical: 'bottom'
            }
        });
    </script>
```

ANd also with orientation like this thread says ([Bootstrap DatePicker Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52116552/bootstrap-datepicker-position)) but didn't work either:

```
    <script>
        $('#dateAssigned').datepicker({
            orientation: "bottom"
        });
    </script>
```

Any hints on how to make pup-up appear on bottom? Thanks.

Comment: Interestingly orientation: bottom worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap DatePicker *defaults* to the bottom; you shouldn't need any additional rules to make it show there. `orientation` would indeed be the way to go to adjust where the popup appears, though it's more likely a problem with incorrectly loading / referencing the DatePicker and its required components.

Ensure that you load the JavaScript for jQuery, Popper, Bootstrap then Bootstrap's DatePicker in that order. Ensure that you load the CSS for Bootstrap, then Bootstrap's DatePicker in that order.

Here's an example showing that:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
  <input id="dateAssigned" name="dateAssigned" type="text" class="form-control mb-4 mt-1" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
  <div class="input-group-addon"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have all the JS files in that order the only thing I have extra is the Material Design Bootstrap files (https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/) as well and I included it at the end after all of the others. Could that be whats potentially causing the issue? Any idea on what CSS would need to be overridden if that's the case?

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could share whole HTML code, or at least everything in-between  and . So we can check what scripts and styles you are loading.

I am 99% sure that you don't have properly loaded Bootstrap CSS for datepicker.

You can get it here directly from Git repository: https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker][1](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker)

or from CDN:
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: Yes I am loading the Bootstrap CSS datepicker. I've been using the standalone one but I did checked with just the bootstrap-datepicker.css as well as bootstrap-datepicker3 and none work either. I think is my MDB CSS that's screwing the CSS for datepicker but I don't know what CSS could be getting overridden by it.