# HTML native <input type="date">- change date picker position

Tags: html, css, input

I am using HTML native input date (this one- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) but in Safari (macOS) my date picker is rendered off screen. How can I either,
(a) disable the date picker or
(b) change its position to appear on top of the input date text field.

[image: Date picker off screen]

[image: Date picker rendering off screen]

Code:

```css
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      background-color: #000000;
    }
    
    #content {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      padding-top: 16px;
    }
    
    #actionHolder {
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-items: center;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: 16px;
    }
    
    input {
      width: auto;
      padding: 16px;
      margin: 4px;
    }
    
    /* ::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
      display: none;
    } */
    
    button {
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      padding: 16px;
      margin: 4px;
      background-color: #e0e0e0;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="actionHolder">
            <input type="text" id="content">
            <input type="date" id="date">
            <button onclick="toggleOnClick()">Toggle</button>
            <button onclick="addOnClick()">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

***Look at the snippet in full page mode to understand the problem (Safari, macOS)***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap DatePicker Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52116552/bootstrap-datepicker-position)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini not using Bootstrap DatePicker, using native input date- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: Post your code please instead of only image.

Comment: Miss js/jquery, add please

Comment: I am not using jquery and there is no relevant js involved

Comment: The snippet work perfectly as you can see. So we can't help you if we can't see problem

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Look at the image/read the description, if the input date element is placed at the bottom of the screen it renders off screen (look at the snippet in full screen mode in Safari on macOS)

Answer (score 0):

To change date picker position
first set a final width of it
eg. width:100px or 10em or 10vw or anything which is fixed
Then the styles are here

```css
#date{
    width:200px;
}    
#date::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field { display:none;}
#date::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field { display:none; }
#date::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field { display:none; }
#date::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { margin-right:100px}
```

Then at last you can use `::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { margin-right:100px}`this and set margins to move here and there

Comment: Hi Lalan, I do not want to hide the day, month and year field. Furthermore, I want to move the position of the calendar that opens after the calendar picker indicator is clicked not the indicator itself.